# Loss of current to fuel pump

Tags: toyota, fuel-system, corolla, fuel-pump

There is no current coming to the fuel pump in my 1997 toyota corolla. Only the ground wire has current. The other wire does not have current so what is the cause of this lost of current and how can I fix it? So Where can I locate the fuel pump relay or fuse?

Comment: Sorry if it's obvious, but have you checked the fuse? Also, see if the fuel pump relay is working. You can lay your finger on the outside and feel or hear it click on when the ignition is turned on.

Comment: Do you mean current?  It must be coming from somewhere.  If you mean voltage, the pump is mis-wired.

Comment: Does it have an inertia switch (turns off pump in case of an accident) - has it had a thump? Try resetting it.